# Regex negative look-behind in hgignore file

Tags: regex, mercurial, hgignore, negative-lookbehind

I'm looking for a way to modify my .hgignore file to ignore all "Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs" files except those in either the "Test/" or the "Tests/" subfolders.

I tried using the negative look-behind expression
`(?<!Test)/Properties/AssemblyInfo\.cs$`, but I didn't find a way to "un-ignore" in **both** folders "Test/" and "Tests/".

Comment: if they are already checked in the .hgignore won't effect them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't support variable-length lookbehind.

But `\b(?<!Test)(?<!Tests)/Properties/AssemblyInfo\.cs$` should work.

Comment: Sweet, this works like a charm. But what's the purpose of 'r'? Is that like the '@' of C# for instance?

Comment: Yes it is, but I just removed this bit again since you don't need this in the .hgignore file, only in a native Python string. Got a little carried away there :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to get this out there for any future searchers:  Regex contortions like this are only necessary if you expect a lot more exception files to be added to the working directory in the future.

If you just want to make the current ones exceptions, you can just `hg add` them.  Unlike svn and cvs, in mercurial you can `add` an ignored file and it overrides the `.hgignore` -- future changes will be automatically tracked.

It's not unheard of to have `.*` in your `.hgignore` file and then `hg add` the files you want tracked.

In this case, The more traditional mercurial way to do this would be a `.hgignore` file like this:

```
/Properties/AssemblyInfo\.cs
```

followed by:

```
$ hg add Test/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
$ hg add Tests/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
```

If you have hundreds of Test and Tests you can add them with a `find`, but if you create new ones every day then the regex is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd just do `Tests?`, but since depending on the regexp engine, dynamic look-behinds aren't allowed, you can simply use two branches:

`(?<!Test|Tests)/Properties/AssemblyInfo\.cs$`

Comment: I already tried that, doesn't work. Mercurial says "invalid pattern". Doesn't this have to do with the look-behind expression having to be of a fixed length?

Comment: Somehow I assumed that PCRE was used, in PCRE different branches can be of different width.